# C++03. Test for rvalue-vs-lvalue at compile-time, not just at runtime

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue, c++03

In C++03, Boost's Foreach, using [this interesting technique](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach3.html), can detect *at run-time* whether an expression is an lvalue or an rvalue. (I found that via this StackOverflow question: [Rvalues in C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025421/rvalues-in-c03) )

Here's a [demo of this working at run-time](http://ideone.com/l9wXE)

(This is a more basic question that arose while I was thinking about this [other recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004831/is-it-possible-to-take-a-parameter-by-const-reference-while-banning-conversions). An answer to this might help us answer that other question.)

*Now that I've spelled out the question, testing rvalue-ness in C++03 at compile-time, I'll talk a little about the things I've been trying so far.*

I want to be able to do this check at *compile-time*. It's easy in C++11, but I'm curious about C++03.

I'm trying to build upon their idea, but would be open to different approaches also. The basic idea of their technique is to put this code into a macro:

```
true ? rvalue_probe() : EXPRESSION;
```

It is 'true' on the left of the `?`, and therefore we can be sure that EXPRESSION will never be evaluated. But the interesting thing is that the `?:` operator behaves differently depending on whether its parameters are lvalues or rvalues (click that link above for details). In particular, it will convert our `rvalue_probe` object in one of two ways, depending on whether EXPRESSION is an lvalue or not:

```
struct rvalue_probe
{
    template< class R > operator       R () { throw "rvalue"; }
    template< class L > operator       L & () const { throw "lvalue"; }
    template< class L > operator const L & () const { throw "const lvalue"; }
};
```

That works at runtime because the thrown text can be caught and used to analyze whether the EXPRESSION was an lvalue or an rvalue. But I want some way to identify, at compile-time, which conversion is being used.

Now, this is potentially useful because it means that, instead of asking

> Is EXPRESSION an rvalue?

we can ask:

> When the compiler is compiling **true ? rvalue_probe() : EXPRESSION**, which of the two overloaded operators, `operator X` or `operator X&`, is selected?

( Ordinarily, you could detect which method was called by changing the return types and getting the `sizeof` it. But we can't do that with these conversion operators, especially when they're buried inside the `?:`. )

I thought I might be able to use something like

```
is_reference< typeof (true ? rvalue_probe() : EXPRESSION) > :: type
```

If the EXPRESSION is an lvalue, then the `operator&` is selected and I hoped that the whole expression would then be a `&` type. But it doesn't seem to work. ref types and non-ref types are pretty hard (impossible?) to distinguish, especially now that I'm trying to dig inside a `?:` expression to see which conversion was selected.

Here's the demo code pasted here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X {
        X(){}
};

X x;
X & xr = x;
const X xc;

      X   foo()  { return x; }
const X   fooc() { return x; }
      X & foor()  { return x; }
const X & foorc() { return x; }

struct rvalue_probe
{
        template< class R > operator       R () { throw "rvalue"; }
        // template< class R > operator R const () { throw "const rvalue"; } // doesn't work, don't know why
        template< class L > operator       L & () const { throw "lvalue"; }
        template< class L > operator const L & () const { throw "const lvalue"; }
};

typedef int lvalue_flag[1];
typedef int rvalue_flag[2];
template <typename T> struct isref     { static const int value = 0; typedef lvalue_flag type; };
template <typename T> struct isref<T&> { static const int value = 1; typedef rvalue_flag type; };

int main() {
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : x;       } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y lvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : xc;      } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y const lvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : xr;      } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y       lvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : foo();   } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y rvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : fooc();  } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y rvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : foor();  } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y lvalue
        try{ true ? rvalue_probe() : foorc(); } catch (const char * result) { cout << result << endl; } // Y const lvalue

}
```

(I had some other code here at the end, but it's just confusing things. You don't really want to see my failed attempts at an answer! The above code demonstrates how it can test lvalue-versus-rvalue *at runtime*.)

Comment: @hvd, I've updated the end of the question accordingly. I should have said `fooref`, not `foo`. But anyway, typeof still thinks that `true ?: fooref() : fooref()` is *not* a reference.

Comment: @hvd, ... I checked `typeof(x)` and `typeof(xr)` also and they are giving the same type, this doesn't make sense to me. There appear to be inconsistencies in `typeof`. I get the right behaviour with `typeof(int&)`, but it doesn't do the same thing with `typeof(xr)`.

Comment: The type and lvalue-ness of `x` and `xr` is the same, so I'm assuming that's why `typeof`'s result is the same. There is subtly different behaviour with `decltype` that might help you out, but your version of g++ doesn't support it.

Comment: You try to invent standard is_lvalue_reference/is_rvalue_reference? Or I miss something.

Comment: @Andrew Now that I see your message, I think the problem is that "x is an lvalue" and "x is a reference" are two different questions, and they are confused in the question.

Comment: @Andrew, is_lvalue_reference is a C++11 feature. I'm wondering how to do this in C++03. C++03 has lvalues and rvalues, and there is this `?:` that is able to distinguish them. I just want to be able take that extra step and detect this at runtime.

Comment: @hvd, I'm not confusing the issue of references with lvalue-rvalue-ness. Boost's FOREACH shows how, in C++03, there is a way to *test* whether a given expression is an *rvalue* by looking at whether another expression based on it is of *reference type*. It's a surprising technique, but it's not a confusion on my part. I can't make it work fully. And I'm deliberately testing every version of every expression I can because I want to be sure that a function that returns a `&` is treated as an lvalue - (const vs. non-const, reference vs. non-reference, return-from-function vs named local variable)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Now you've lost me. `x` is an lvalue, it gets treated as an rvalue, and your comment claims the behaviour for `x` is correct. Why is that correct, then?

Comment: You are confused. Expressions can't have reference types. They are always either of type void or of object or function types.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, that's perhaps a clearer way of explaining. It means `xr` as an expression is an lvalue expression that has type `X`. `x` as an expression is *also* an lvalue expression that has type `X`.

Comment: OK. Let's take a step back. I'm happy to delete most of my question and leave the raw question: "How do we replicate *at compile-time*, the functionality that Boost's FOREACH can do so well *at run-time*?". The page I linked to make clear that the underlying question is about lvalue-vs-rvalue i C++03.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid In that case, doesn't the usual trick of `char (&helper(...))[1];` / `template <typename T> char (&helper(T&))[2];` / `#define is_lvalue(x) (sizeof(helper(x)) == 2)` work?

Comment: I've changed the end of the question. The code I had at the end wasn't relevant. I understand the comments, but it doesn't help me to any closer to ultimate question. @JohannesSchaub-litb, an 'expression' (is that the right word?) has a 'value-category' (again, is this the right word?). If you follow the link to the Boost page you'll see clearly how the lvalue-or-rvalue-ness of an expression is related to whether `operator X` or `operator X&` is called as a converter. This is the thing I'm trying to leverage *at compile time*.

Comment: @hvd, I've just realised that the 'reference-ness' of the type is slightly missing the point. The question I should have asked near the end of my question is "*How do we detect, at compile-time, which overloaded conversion operator (`operator X` or `operator X&`) was selected?*". I'll update my question.

Comment: @Aaron right, but whether one of those is called has nothing to do with the type of the expression.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Which one gets called depends exclusively on the lvalue-ness of the unevaluated expression, so if you already have a test (see my earlier comment) that tests the lvalue-ness in another way, what do you need beyond that? You could write `is_lvalue(true ? rvalue_probe() : x)`, which would give you the same result as `is_lvalue(x)`. I may well be missing something, but it would be helpful if you could clarify just what that something is.

Comment: @hvd, when I look at those kinds of solutions, I often find that they break on `const` lvalues. A `const` lvalue seems to appear very like an rvalue. I'll play around with that `helper` you mentioned.

Comment: @hvd, that helper is working. It gets the wrong answer in just one case, it thinks that `const X fooc();` is an lvalue. But it's pretty weird to have const in a return value like this, so it's not a problem.  But if it is that simple, then why did Boost's FOREACH go to so much trouble? ***:-)*** Maybe I'm missing something more obvious :-)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yuck, you're right. A `const X` rvalue is a valid argument for a `const X &` function parameter, and that is the overload that gets used. Hold on...

Comment: @Xeo I'm seeing `T&` with an rvalue argument of type int deduced to `T = int`, which makes it an error. I suspect you know better than me whether that's correct.

Comment: @hvd: Nevermind, I somehow made the wrong assumption that `T&` fed with an rvalue of type `X` will deduce to `X const&`. This is not the case, as such my previous comments don't apply. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took some effort, but here's a tested and working `is_lvalue` macro that correctly handles `const struct S` function return types. It relies on `const struct S` rvalues not binding to `const volatile struct S&`, while `const struct S` lvalues do.

```
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
struct nondeducible
{
  typedef T type;
};

char (& is_lvalue_helper(...))[1];

template <typename T>
char (& is_lvalue_helper(T&, typename nondeducible<const volatile T&>::type))[2];

#define is_lvalue(x) (sizeof(is_lvalue_helper((x),(x))) == 2)

struct S
{
  int i;
};

template <typename T>
void test_()
{
  T a = {0};
  T& b = a;
  T (* c)() = 0;
  T& (* d)() = 0;
  assert (is_lvalue(a));
  assert (is_lvalue(b));
  assert (!is_lvalue(c()));
  assert (is_lvalue(d()));
}

template <typename T>
void test()
{
  test_<T>();
  test_<const T>();
  test_<volatile T>();
  test_<const volatile T>();
}

int main()
{
  test<int>();
  test<S>();
}
```

*Edit*: unnecessary extra parameter removed, thanks Xeo.

*Edit again*: As per the comments, this works with GCC but relies on unspecified behaviour in C++03 (it's valid C++11) and fails some other compilers. Extra parameter restored, which makes it work in more cases. const class rvalues give a hard error on some compilers, and give the correct result (false) on others.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, Clang spews way to many errors with that for some reason... Clang also errors on your previous version, with the complete error shown [here](http://ideone.com/bCPPm). That might be a Clang bug, though.

Comment: Ok, all of comeau, gcc and clang accept also function lvalues with Xeo's version. That clang and comeau rejects that code has to do with a clarification of C++11. They clarified that only const *non-volatile* references can bind to rvalues. C++03 just said that "binding a reference to non-const to an rvalue" is not possible. C++11 added the non-volatile part. That they still reject it in C++03 is because the reference binding itself is still ill-formed, even if overload resolution itself accepts the conversion.

Comment: Why does this work? Is it because rvalues shouldn't have any other references to them and hence are less 'volatile' than lvalues? I never really paid attention to `volatile` before - thanks for motivating me to read up on it!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is that a clarification or a change in behaviour? If this code works with GCC in C++03 mode because it implements the C++11 semantics, that's not something I'm happy with :)

Comment: @Johannes: *Can* doesn't imply *must*, so I think it's well formed, unless some other paragraph says it isn't. Also, on the "cv ref in C++03" issue: Why is the binding still ill-formed?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It's because function with a parameter with type `const volatile S&` cannot be called with an `const S` rvalue argument. There's a special exception that *does* allow it with `const S&`, but that exception doesn't apply to `const volatile S&`. (At least, that's the case with GCC. Whether it's true per C++03 is still an open question.)

Comment: @hvd I think I would take it more as a clarification but I'm so sad that clang and comeau online reject it! And please disregard my comments about function lvalues. I think it works fine with them.

Comment: @Xeo yes I think it compares "T const volatile" against "void()" (for a "void()" function lvalue) to find a match. Now "T const volatile" is const and volatile qualified, but "void()" is none of them, so they mismatch. I guess now the question is whether to transform "T const volatile" to "T" and compare again and succeed, or to try to transform "void()" to "const volatile identity<void()>::type", and be at square one, getting "void()" again and again mismatching. Apparently existing compilers choose the former route and succeed deducing T.

Comment: 3.9.3 defines "cv-qualified" only for object-types and "void" (which can serve as a source to disambiguate the above choice-ambiguity). So an impl rejecting function lvalues would seem entirely sensible to me, after all the "deduced A" is still not more cv-qualified than the original transformed A.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks, but I'm confused: [over.match.viable] says "If the parameter has reference type, the implicit conversion
sequence includes the operation of binding the reference", so if the binding is not valid, shouldn't the overload be removed? Or am I reading a later draft?

Comment: @Johannes: Back to [the clang error message](http://ideone.com/bCPPm) from the previous version: You said that the reference binding is still ill-formed for some reason in C++03. Why?

Comment: @hvd that the implicit conversion seqence includes the operation of binding the reference means that "X&" cannot bind to an rvalue. And that "X&" is preferred over "X const&" if both work (this is *not* a qualification conversion, but a special case!). It doesn't refer to the actual initialization of the parameter that happens after overload resolution selected the function. It's the overload-resolution reference binding, so to speak.

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, so it's a bug if read in one way, and conforming if read another way in C++03?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb [over.ics.ref] seems not to answer it either way: it first says that binding a non-const reference to a temporary is a no-go, it then says that other restrictions not based on the type of the reference and the argument are not checked. But this is another restriction that *is* based on the type of the reference and the argument.

Comment: @Johannes: I'm thinking that this might call for a defect report to the C++ standard. It either needs to be clarified, or the overload resolution ICS rules need to be adjusted to match the normal ref binding rules. Opinions?

Comment: @Xeo C++11 is clear on the issue: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1152

Comment: @hvd: Ah, okay. I think I got it now... Binding an rvalue to ref-to-cv is completely ill-formed in C++11 and should exclude an overload from the set of matches (Clang buggy here). In C++03, it's fuzzy and not clear. Correct?

Comment: @Xeo Yes, pretty much, you're not allowed to bind an rvalue to a ref-to-cv in either C++11 or C++03, but C++11 actually says this causes overloads to be excluded, and C++03 is silent on that last part.

Comment: Hey guys, I read those comments but it's mostly too advanced for me :-) Thanks anyway, I think I picked up something. Anyway, what's the bottom line? That there might be a c++03 compiler which binds `const volatile &` to an rvalue, *and* that they could almost argue they are a conforming compiler? And C++11 is clearer on the topic - that this behaviour is just not allowed?

Comment: @hvd no. the existence of a conversion sequence is independent of whether the initialization of a variable is well formed. Overload resolution is eager, it accepts conversions of arguments to parameters even if the initialization of the parameter will later be ill-formed. For example, access violations (private base class), and this very reference initialization issue. The inconsistency you mention was fixed in C++11, but nontheless an inconsistency is not necessarily a contradiction.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I didn't claim otherwise; the standard specifically addresses some cases where overload resolution doesn't discard a function even though it won't be callable. What I'm saying is that the description of reference binding is clear in what is and isn't included, except for this one corner case, which is included by some compilers (matching C++11) and excluded by others.

Answer (score 1):

The address-of operator (`&`) can only be used with an lvalue.  So if you used it in an SFINAE test, you could distinguish at compile-time.

A static assertion could look like:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT_IS_LVALUE(x) ( (sizeof &(x)), (x) )
```

A trait version might be:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_lvalue_subscript
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    yes fn( char (*)[sizeof (&(((T*)0)->operator[](0))] );
    no fn(...);
    enum { value = sizeof(fn(0)) == 1 };
};
```

and could be used like

```
has_lvalue_subscript< std::vector<int> >::value
```

(Warning: not tested)

I can't think of any way to test an arbitrary expression valid in the caller's context, without breaking compilation on failure.

Comment: Can the address-of operator not be used with rvalues of class type that have their own `operator&` function?

Comment: I like this. It's not a full solution yet, but it is correct. I'm experimenting a little with this now.

Comment: @hvd: It's hard to say what result you want for a class weird enough to overload `operator&`.  It probably is trying to transparently wrap an lvalue, in which case maybe this test should say it IS an lvalue.

Comment: I think I envisage having a macro called `STATIC_ASSERT_IS_LVALUE(x)` which will cause a compilation failure if x isn't an lvalue (and which will also evaluate to x). Taking the `&` would be good enough for me. If we can just write up the assertion, then I think I'll accept this. What about using the comma operator? `#define STATIC_ASSERT_IS_LVALUE(x) ( (typeof(&x) ) 0 , x)`

Comment: ... ultimately, it would be nice if it did something other than force a compilation error. For example, somebody might want a `STATIC_ASSERT_IS_RVALUE` instead. But the former would be good enough for me.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid That one's easier: `reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>((x))` is a hard error if `x` is not an lvalue -- that one does work with `const T` function return types.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You can of course wrap that in `sizeof` to get an unevaluated expression.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid And by "does work" I mean "does generate the intended error"

Comment: Definitely prefer `sizeof` over `typeof`, since `sizeof` is standard.